# jHipster, Keycloak - How to update user data on keycloak correctly?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jhipster, keycloak, openid-connect, keycloak-rest-api

I'm trying to figure out the best method to exchange user information between a Spring application, and an Identity Provider.
To be specific, it's an application generated with jHipster, using Keycloak as the IdP.

The data exchange can be done easily with [keycloak-admin-client](https://search.maven.org/search?q=a:keycloak-admin-client), the problem is that after the update, *the client still haves the same Access Token in memory*, basically it's not in sync with the new data sent to Keycloak.

Do you know which is the best method to handle this situation?

I tried to invalidate the current access token, in order to force the client app to ask for a new one using the refresh token. But apparently there's no way to do this with the admin-client (at least, I couldn't find it).

At this point I don't see other options then asking for a new access token from client, once it sends an user data update request.

It doesn't seem a proper solution to me, I feel like maybe there's a more "elegant" procedure for this situations.

If you have any better solution, I'm all ears.